# Merging .sp files (from Perkin Elmer) into a matrix using R

Tags: r, matrix, merge

I am quite a novice in R. I have data from a spectrophotometer and I would like to treat all my data once.

I have a huge directory with 45 .sp files for each sample (with about 200 samples, for the moment). I would like to build a matrix for each sample by merging the 45 files into one matrix with emission and extraction as column and row names. The file name is defined as : blahblah#01.sp, blahblah#02.sp to blahblah#45.sp (for the first sample), toptop#01.sp, toptop#45.sp, and in the same directory I have all the other samples.

Is it possible to merge all the sp files with the same prefix (with #01.sp...) into one matrix, and for all the samples...

So far I have tried this:

```
## Set up data paths and read mask from file
setwd("C:/EEMs/")
getwd()

## Define paths for data, results table
datainpath<-"C:/EEMs/rawdata/"
dataoutpath<-"C:/EEMs/results/"


## Get list of sp files in the data directory that will be processed and print a list
files<-list.files(datainpath,pattern="\\.sp$")
print(files)

filename<-substring(files,1,nchar(files)-6)
print(filename)


### - 2. Define excitation and emission ranges for matrix
emission<-seq(250,600.5,0.5) # define emission wavelength range for matrix (start, finish, by) (nm)
excitation<-seq(200,420,5)# define excitation wavelength range for matrix (start, finish, by) (nm)
# Number of files per spectral
nfic<-45
# # Number of measurements per spectral
nc<-702

### - 3. Read in sample and blank EEMs files
## - 3.1.: Start loop through files in data folder
for (Samplefile in files) {

filename2<-paste(dataoutpath,filename,"#",as.character(0),as.character(1),".sp",sep="")
fich<-matrix(scan(filename2,skip=54),ncol=2,byrow=T)

dataechant<-matrix(NA,nrow=nc,ncol=nfic)
dimnames(dataechant)<-list(as.character(emission),as.character(excitation))
dataechant[,1]<-fich[,2]
for (i in 2:9)

{
filename2<-paste(dataoutpath,filename,"#",as.character(0),as.character(i),".sp",sep="")
fich<-matrix(scan(filename2,skip=54),ncol=2,byrow=T)
dataechant[,i]<-fich[,2]
}
for (i in 10:45)
 {
filename2<-paste(dataoutpath,filename,"#",as.character(i),".sp",sep="")
fich<-matrix(scan(filename2,skip=54),ncol=2,byrow=T)
dataechant[,i]<-fich[,2]
}
}

#Export to EEM result dir 
write.csv2(dataechant,paste("results/",filename,".csv"))
```

Please let me know if I am on the right path.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow.  Here's a hint to working w/ software: try each step by itself and see if the output is what you want.  Then get back to us about the step which is not producing the desired result.

Comment: Hi,thank you for your advice. I have tried to print the list of files. That's OK... then, I would like to know how I can reduce the list of files having the same prefix. This new list would be used to run another script, hopefully.